# Turning windows 7/8 into VPN router

Tags: router, vpn

I am currently trying to turn my pc running windows 7  (storage media server with flexraid) into a VPN router that allows other devices to access the media content (works fine now) and allow other devices to access netflix once they connect to it through wifi/lan. Using ofcourse strongvpn/hma or samiliar service.

How can I turn storage server to VPN router on windows 7

Comment: So whats your question sorry?

Comment: Trying to add VPN router feature to my storage server on windows 7 Instead of buying router with VPN function.

Comment: Ah ok cool well I would use the Windows 7 Network VPN abilities.. too long for comment so will answer below...

Comment: You should give a little more information about what you are trying to achieve. You can set up your computer to act as a VPN server, and other computers connect to your VPN to access it (e.g. to bypass firewall etc), or you could create a VPN connection to another location (e.g. US if you're living in the UK) to access more Netflix content, and then share that connection with your other computers. It is not clear what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above you can follow these steps to get a Windows 7 VPN up and running, works really well got a few running around the UK.

First, you’ll need to open the Network Connections window.

File menu select New Incoming Connection.

You can now select the user accounts that can connect remotely. To increase security, you may want to create a new, limited user account rather than allow VPN logins from your user account.

Select the Through the Internet option to allow VPN connections over the Internet.

You can then select the networking protocols that should be enabled for incoming connections. For example, as you want file access make sure you check the File and Printer Sharing option.

Click the Allow access button and Windows will set up a VPN server.

Comment: Remembering you will need to setup port forward on your router/firewall to send the PPTP port from outside world to this machine (Port 1723). Thanks

Comment: PPTP is a very weak on security!

Comment: I'm to slow for Superuser ( ._.)

Comment: @Jakke that it is! however watching Netflix I'm sure they'll be fine :)

Comment: @Kimmax haha quickly quickly!

Answer (score -1):

Go to the Network and Sharing Center and select *Change adapter settings* from the left. In this windows press the *Alt* key and go to *File-> New incoming connection*. Check the checkbox next to each user you wan't to grant access and/or add additional users via the *Add someone* button. Check *Through the Internet* on the next page and go to the next page. Enable any protocols you wish to use (Note that you should enable at least *Internet Protocol Version 4* and *File and Printer for M$ Networks* if you wan't to be able to share files). Make sure that in the property's of the *IPv4* protocol *Allow callers to access my local area network* is enabled, you may spefic an ip-adress range here. Click *Ok* and *Allow access*. On the next page hit *Close*. Make sure that TCP-Port 1723 is not blocked by your pc or router and you're done. You can connect to the VPN via your IP and one of the user accounts specified earlier.

Comment: Downvote for what?